# Why does this scala code only execute the last future when necessary?

Tags: scala

From https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html:

> A very nice feature of Futures is that they are highly composable.
>   Consider the following problem. I want to return an HTTP result to a
>   user based on the following criteria:
>
> If a cookie is set, I'll return them a result from the cookie. If I
>   have seen the user before but they have no cookie, I probably stored a
>   result in Redis. I'd like to return that result. If neither of the
>   previous two criteria holds, I'd like to build them a result from
>   scratch. This is time consuming and requires a database hit, provided
>   a result is not in the cache. With futures, the code to do this is:

```
def processRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = {
  val fromRequest: Option[HttpResponse] = getFromCookie(request)
  fromRequest.map( r => Future { r }).getOrElse({
    val fromRedis = getFromRedis(request)
    //getFromRedis will return an unsuccessful future object if redis does not contain anything
    val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)

    //On any error in fromRedis, build from scratch
    val result = fromRedis.recoverWith({ case _ => fromScratch })

    result
})
```

From reading this, I'd expect that the line `val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)` would cause this expensive function to be executed at that point. If I were writing this I would have written the following instead:

```
    val fromRedis = getFromRedis(request)

    //On any error in fromRedis, build from scratch
    val result = fromRedis.recoverWith({ case r => getFromScratch(r) })
```

So I guess Futures can be passed around and are only executed when you try to complete them with some function like `getOrElse`, `recoverWith`, etc., or is there something else going on with the code I quoted?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this is off topic for Code Review as questions must contain code that you either own or maintain. CR isn't for explaining how code works, it's for giving feedback on people's existing code. Read the [site tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) to see more about what's on topic here.

Comment: My question is why doesn't the line `val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)` cause the expensive function to be executed at that point? The author says it's only run in the `recoverWith` block.

Comment: Questions of the form "Why doesn't this code do what I think it should do" belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> From reading this, I'd expect that the line `val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)` would cause this expensive function to be executed at that point.

The methods used on the futures indicate that the author uses the scala library Future, therefore, your understanding is correct, the expensive function will indeed be executed at this point. It's result will be ignored whenever

The following code will make this more obvious by using side effects:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.control.NoStackTrace
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case object NotFound extends NoSuchElementException with NoStackTrace

def getFromCookie(request:String)={
  if(request=="cookie") Some("cookie")
  else None
}
def getFromRedis(request:String)={
  println("getting from redis")
  if(request=="redis") Future.successful("redis")
  else Future.failed(NotFound)
}
def getFromScratch(request:String)={
  val a= "scratch"
  println("computing from scratch = "+a)
  System.out.flush()
  if(request=="scratch") Future.successful(a)
  else Future.failed(NotFound)
}

def processRequest(request: String): Future[String] = {
  val fromRequest: Option[String] = getFromCookie(request)
  fromRequest.map(r => Future {
    r
  }).getOrElse({
    val fromRedis = getFromRedis(request)
    //getFromRedis will return an unsuccessful future object if redis does not contain anything
    val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)

    //On any error in fromRedis, build from scratch
    val result = fromRedis.recoverWith({ case _ => fromScratch })

    result
  })
}
```

results in

```
scala> val a= Await.result(processRequest("cookie") ,1.second)
a: String = cookie

scala> val b= Await.result(processRequest("redis")  , 1.second)
getting from redis
computing from scratch = scratch
b: String = redis

scala> val c= Await.result(processRequest("scratch"),1.second)
getting from redis
computing from scratch = scratch
c: String = scratch
```

As you can see, in both the `redis` and `scratch` cases, both `getting from redis` and `computing from scratch` were executed.

Changing the process request definition to what you propose

```
def processRequest(request: String): Future[String] = {
  val fromRequest: Option[String] = getFromCookie(request)
  fromRequest.map(r => Future {
    r
  }).getOrElse({
    val fromRedis = getFromRedis(request)
    //getFromRedis will return an unsuccessful future object if redis does not contain anything
//    val fromScratch = getFromScratch(request)
    //On any error in fromRedis, build from scratch
    val result = fromRedis.recoverWith({ case NotFound => getFromScratch(request)})

    result
  })
}
```

indeed results in the expensive computation to be run only when needed

```
scala> val a= Await.result(processRequest("cookie") ,1.second)
a: String = cookie

scala> val b= Await.result(processRequest("redis")  , 1.second
     | )
getting from redis
b: String = redis

scala> val c= Await.result(processRequest("scratch"),1.second)
getting from redis
computing from scratch = scratch
c: String = scratch
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought perhaps I'd overlooked an important feature of futures.

Comment: scalaz futures would behave differently as they don't run immediately upon creation, you have to explicitely trigger the computation which allows for easier reasoning :)